# Array Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm running a RegEx to match all instances of the Twitter hashtag. It returns it just fine, but now I just want to loop through the first set and return my #hello, #world, #hello-world....not the second set. Any help will be quickly rewarded!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #hello
            [1] =>  #world
            [2] =>  #hello-world
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => world
            [2] => hello-world
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `$arr[0]` as the array you want to iterate:

```
foreach ($arr[0] as $tag) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean `foreach($array[0] as $string) {...`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to loop through.
You can just do

```
return $matches[0];
```

This will return

```
Array (
        [0] => #hello
        [1] =>  #world
        [2] =>  #hello-world
    )
```